# Godaddy: Only redirect a certain port?

Tags: subdomain

I am trying to redirect http://www.club.example.com to something, but ONLY if they use the port 25565. If they go to port 80, it will redirect them to a website. So basically:[image]
It should be worth noting if it goes to the Minecraft server, that is running on my computer and can be accessed with my_public_ip:25565.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In php you can do like this:

```
<?php

$port=$_SERVER['SERVER_PORT'];

if ($port==25565)
    // redirect minecraft server
else
    // show website


?>
```

Comment: Nope, you can allow for listening port 25565 on IIS or Apache